# Preserve variables in a javascript closure function

Tags: javascript, closures

I am pretty much a novice in javascript programming and i would really need some help/advice.

What i am trying to do:
I have a function (or object?!) which looks like this:

```
var svgInteraction = function (containerId) {
    var svgNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        htmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
    mathns = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML";

    svgInteractions = {};

    svgInteractions[containerId] = "I am " + containerId;
    console.log(svgInteractions);

    return function () {
        console.log(svgInteractions);
    }
};
```

i initialize a variable like this:

```
var svg1 = svgInteraction("container_1");
var svg2 = svgInteraction("container_2");
```

The problem is that, for each initialization of the svgInteraction, the svgInteractions objects reinitialize.

It outputs:

```
Object { container_1="I am container_1"}
Object { container_2="I am container_2"}
```

Is there any way to keep old values inside it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set it to an empty object each time (`svgInteractions = {}`) the function is called.

Try this...

```
var svgInteraction = (function() {

   var svgInteractions = {};

   return function(containerId) {
     // Implementation
   }

})();
```

Here, `svgInteractions` is encapsulated but it will also be *static* for all calls to `svgInteraction`.

Comment: Thank you.
All the implementation code should be inside of return function right? It is like a init() ?
Another question:
How can i keep independent variables/functions for each initialization? For example, i want a different 'click' function to be executed depending on the container.

I was thinking about something like
`svgInteractions[containerId].clickfunction = function() { ... }`

Comment: @GavanCatalin Yep, you are correct. Anything you want to be initialised per call should be in the function body.